# Writing to XMP metadata in python platform agnostic

Tags: python, python-3.x, metadata, xmp

The most common method for writing to XMP metadata in a given file with python appears to be the `Python XMP Toolkit` https://github.com/python-xmp-toolkit/python-xmp-toolkit

Unfortunately this toolkit doesn't appear to work on Windows (or at least doesn't have very clear instructions as to how to get it to work on Windows). Is there another method to write XMP metadata to a video file with python that will work on both Windows and macOS?

Comment: Hi, I'm searching a straightforward method to write XMP metadata to an image file with python on Windows. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Pyexiv2 can read both EXIF and XMP data, and works well on Windows 10.

```
from pyexiv2 import Image    

img_path=r'S1001679.jpg'
img=pyexiv2.Image(img_path)    
img_xmp=img.read_xmp()
img_xmp
```

Return:

```
{'Xmp.xmp.ModifyDate': '2021-02-11T20:21:06Z', 'Xmp.xmp.CreateDate':     '2021-02-11T20:21:06Z', 'Xmp.xmp.CreatorTool': '2d3686e931da45b78bd1cf1e858b1fe8',
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 1):

http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/ is now marked obsolete, but it should hopefully work (if http://www.exiv2.org/ is also installed).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [@icypy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140449/icypy) the pyexiv2 library is very useful for modifying XMP-tags within video/image files.

I definitely can recommend the documentation found on github:
https://github.com/LeoHsiao1/pyexiv2/blob/master/docs/Tutorial.md

Here is a simple example how I used it to update the
`<crs:HasCrop>True</crs:HasCrop>`-tags:

```py
#-----------------------------------------------------------
from pyexiv2 import Image

def print_xmp_tags_all(xmp):
    for key, value in xmp.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(key, value))

def print_xmp_tags_crop(xmp):
    print()
    print("Xmp.crs.HasCrop:     {}".format(xmp['Xmp.crs.HasCrop']))
    print("Xmp.crs.CropBottom:  {}".format(xmp['Xmp.crs.CropBottom']))
    print("Xmp.crs.CropLeft:    {}".format(xmp['Xmp.crs.CropLeft']))
    print("Xmp.crs.CropRight:   {}".format(xmp['Xmp.crs.CropRight']))
    print("Xmp.crs.CropTop:     {}".format(xmp['Xmp.crs.CropTop']))

#-----------------------------------------------------------
img_path = 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/MY_IMAGE_0001.jpg'
img = Image(img_path)
# Extract XMP-metadata from file:
xmp = img.read_xmp()
print_xmp_tags_crop(xmp)
# Preparing dictionary containing only those tags we want do update:
new_xmp = {
    'Xmp.crs.HasCrop':      False,
    'Xmp.crs.CropBottom':   0,
    'Xmp.crs.CropLeft':     0,
    'Xmp.crs.CropRight':    0,
    'Xmp.crs.CropTop':      0
}
# Update XMP-tags within file:
img.modify_xmp(new_xmp)
# Free resources:
img.close()

#-----------------------------------------------------------
# Check if xmp-update was successfull:
img = Image(img_path)
xmp = img.read_xmp()
print_xmp_tags_crop(xmp)
img.close()
```

Corresponding output:

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop>python XMP_flush_attribute_HasCrop.py

Xmp.crs.HasCrop:     True
Xmp.crs.CropBottom:  1
Xmp.crs.CropLeft:    0.056000
Xmp.crs.CropRight:   0.944000
Xmp.crs.CropTop:     0

Xmp.crs.HasCrop:     False
Xmp.crs.CropBottom:  0
Xmp.crs.CropLeft:    0
Xmp.crs.CropRight:   0
Xmp.crs.CropTop:     0
```

HTH